# Add xlim to Stacked Bar

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add a year xtick to the stacked bar chart that represents zero data for the year 2021. Setting the xlim will not work with this method. How do I accomplish this?

```
df.plot(x='year', kind='bar', stacked=True, width = .5, color=['red', 'green'], 
        title='Stacked Bar Chart Pandas Dataframe', 
        figsize=(14,8))

plt.xlim(2016,2021)
```

[stacked bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27PaO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try plt.xticks(). You can pass a list of lables, with 2021 in it, but as no data exits it will just be empty?

If needed also add a column for 2021 in you data with just no values, so like 2021 exits but as a placebo and will have no bar in the chart

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Using labels does not work b/c there needs to be as many data points as labels; I need one more in this case, and potentially more on other data sets. I could add a column, but this is part of a template and needs to not be manually adjusted.